# Distance of average of points to center of minimum enclosing ball

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $v_1, ..., v_n$ be distinct points in $\{0,1\}^d$ with the same norm $\|v_i\|_2=k$ (i.e each $v_i$ has $k$ ones). Let $A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$ be their average, and let $C$ be the center of their minimum enclosing ball. Assume $n \gg d > k$.

What is a good upper bound for $\|A-C\|_2$ in terms of $d,k,n$?

Since $A$ is in the minimum enclosing ball, $\|A-C\|$ is at most the radius of that ball, which has diameter at most $\sqrt{2k}$. So by [Jung's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem), the radius of that ball and $\|A-C\|$ are both at most $\sqrt{2k}\sqrt{\frac{d}{2(d+1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{kd}{d+1}}$.

Can we get a better bound using $n$?

Comment: @Matt F. Thanks for the edit, the question is much clearer.

Comment: Consider $f:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}^c$ by $(f(x))_i=1_{i\le cx}$. This induces a map from $[0,1]^d$ to $\{0,1\}^{cd}$, and I suspect that using the induced map to transfer examples and bounds will make the problem equivalent to a continuous version.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $d=2\cdot k$.
If $d$ is large, then the vertices of the cube such that $\|v\|=k$ lie very densely in $(d-1)$-dimensional sphere.

If $n$ is large, but not that large, then you may choose $n-1$ points near one pole of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ and 1 point near the opposite pole.
In this case the $\|A-C\|$ is very close to the worst case.

Comment: Thanks. The point here is that $n \gg d$. For example, something of the order $\gg d^d$, so I'm wondering if the average gets it closer to its "right" position. At least in 2D, 3D (the only thing I can visualize), it gets really close on almost all examples I tried.

Comment: @AspiringMat, wait, $n\leqslant \binom dk\leqslant 2^d$, so order $d^d$ makes no sense.

Comment: @AspiringMat if $n$ is of order $\binom  dk$, then, by the concentration of measure phenomenon, $\|A-C\|$ is very small. My argument shows that this is not so if $n$ is much smaller than $\binom  dk$, it still can be much larger that $d$.